# Are there any specific modifiers you have to have active for sculpting?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I just learned why sculpting wasn't working in blender for me and it was so dumb lol. all surfaces that you want to sculpt have to have a subdivision on them, I guess my question is, did I just get lucky and find that out because I missed a step or is that like a known rule or fact that you should have your subdivision modifiers on when sculpting?

Comment: Having a Subdivision Surface modifier won't change anything as it doesn't add topology for real, you'll still sculpt on the low resolution mesh, if you want enough topology to sculpt on, either apply the Subdivision Surface modifier (but before that maybe make sure that you keep a low resolution version of your object), or use a method suggested by Alex, there's also the Dyntopo tool

Comment: I’m going to try this out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when sculpting with a subdivision modifier, you only sculpt on the base layer of the geometry, which means you cant really add fine details on your mesh.

However, you can use the multiresolition modifier, which allows you to sculpt on all subdivision levels, while conserving the original topology.

It's also pretty common to just use remesh, which will change the topology's resolution depending on the value you set. It's very useful for models that are not made to be subdivided

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and I’m still super new to using blender so you have no idea how much your photo reference helped me understand! Lol